# Javascript calculations working in IE only

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to create a form so that user can enter certain information and JavaScript will do the calculations for them. I've been trying to use http://demo.rsjoomla.com/calculation-form-example (the one on the left) to get the basics started and I can manipulate from there. So far though it's only working in IE.

Here's the basic layout of my code:

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="income1" value="0" onkeyup="update()">
<input type="number" name="income2" value="0" onkeyup="update()">
<input type="number" name="income3" value="0" onkeyup="update()">
```

JavaScript

```
var op1=document.getElementById('income1');
var op2=document.getElementById('income2');
var result=document.getElementById('income3');
if(op1.value=="" || op1.value!=parseFloat(op1.value)) op1.value=0;
if(op2.value=="" || op2.value!=parseFloat(op2.value)) op2.value=0;
result.value=0;
result.value=parseInt(result.value);
result.value=parseInt(result.value)+parseInt(op1.value) - parseInt(op2.value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do getElementById, you need to have an ID in your element.

```
<input type="number" id="income1" value="0" onkeyup="update()">

var op1=document.getElementById('income1');
```

Or you could use jQuery (requires including jQuery source):

```
<input type="number" name="income1" value="0" onkeyup="update()">

var op1 = ${"input[name=income1]").val();
```

Alternatively, you could do this, assuming you only have one element named income1. This isn't a very good way to do this, but it should work.

```
<input type="number" name="income1" value="0" onkeyup="update()">

var op1=document.getElementsByName('income1')[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

You wrote code that is looking for id

```
document.getElementById('income1');
```

Where is the id on the input?

```
<input type="number" name="income1" value="0" onkeyup="update()">
```

Name is not the same thing as id.

And your parseFloat check, you probably should look at [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). And you are using `parseInt()` at the bottom, and you are using `parseFloat()` above!

Comment: Ok, I feel really small right now. I was trying using getElementByName earlier trying something else and apparently when I started the next I missed that getting it changed back. Now that I can actually add/subtract on to the rest of the form.Thank you for finding my stupid mistake.